# Implement a firestore infinite scolling list which updates on collection changes

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, bloc

**What am I trying to accomblish?**

I am currently facing a bunch of problems implementing a real time updated infinite scrolling list with the firestore backend.

In my application I want to display comments (like in e.g. YouTube or other social media sites) to the user. Since the number of comments in a collection might be quite big, I see an option to paginate the collection, while receiving real time updates based on snapshots. So I initially load `x` comments with the option to load up to `x` more items whenever the user presses a button. In the image below `x = 3`.

[image]

**The standard solution**

Based on other SO questions I figured out that one is supposed to use the `.limit()` and the `.startAfter()` methods to implement such behaviour. 
So the first page is loaded as:

```
query = this
    .collection
    .orderBy('date', descending: true)
    .limit(pageSize);
query.snapshots().map((QuerySnapshot snap) {
  lastVisible = snap.documents.last;
  // convert the DocumentSnapshot into model object
});
```

All additional pages are loaded with the following code:

```
query = this.collection
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .startAfterDocument(lastVisible)
        .limit(pageSize);
```

Furthermore, I'd like to add that this code is located in a repository class which is used with the BLoC pattern similar to the code shown in [Felix Angelov's Flutter Todos Tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttertodostutorial). 
While Felix uses a simple flutter list to show the items, I have a list of pages showing comments based on the data provided by their BLoCs. Note that each BLoC accesses a shared repository (parts of the repository code is shown below).

**The Problem with the standard solution**

With the code shown above I see multiple problems:

1. If a comment is inserted in the middle of the ordered collection (how is not of importance), the added comment is shown because of the Stream provided by the snapshot. However, another comment that already existed is not longer shown because of the `.limit()` operator in the query. One could increase the limit by one but I'm not sure how to edit a snapshot query. In the case that editing a snapshot query is not possible, one could create a new (and bigger) query, but that would cost additional reads.
2. Similar to 1., if a comment in the middle is deleted, the snapshot will return a list which does not longer contain the deleted comment, however another comment (which is already covered by a different page) appears. E.g., in the scenario shown in the image above 5 comments are loaded. Assuming that comment 3 is deleted, comment 2 will show twice.

**Improving the standard solution**

Based on these two problems discussed above, I decided that the solution is not sufficient and I implemented a solution which first loads `x` items by obtaining two "interval" documents. Then a query which fetches the required items in an interval using `.startAtDocument()` and `.endAtDocument()` is created, which eliminates the `.limit()` operator.

```
DocumentSnapshot pageStartDocument;
DocumentSnapshot pageEndDocument;
Future<Stream<List<Comment>>> comments() async {
    // This fetches the first and next Document as initialization
    // (maybe should be implemented in constructor)
    if (pageStartDocument == null) {
      Query query = collection
          .orderBy('date', descending: true)
          .limit(pageSize);
      QuerySnapshot snap = await query.getDocuments();
      pageStartDocument = snap.documents.first;
      pageEndDocument = snap.documents.last;
    } else {
      Query query = collection
          .orderBy('date', descending: true)
          .startAfterDocument(pageEndDocument)
          .limit(pageSize);
      QuerySnapshot snap = await query.getDocuments();
      pageStartDocument = snap.documents.first;
      pageEndDocument = snap.documents.last;
    }

    // This fetches a subcollection of elements from the collection
    // with the tradeof of double the reads
    Query query = this
        .collection
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .startAtDocument(pageStartDocument)
        .endAtDocument(pageEndDocument);

    return query.snapshots().asyncMap((QuerySnapshot snap) async {
      // convert the QuerySnapshot into model objects
    });
```

As commented in the code, this solution has the following drawback:

1. Since a query is required to obtain the `pageStartDocument` and `pageEndDocument`, the number of reads is doubled, because all the data is read again when the second query is created. The performance impact might be neglectable because I believe the data is cashed, however having 2x database read cost can be significant.

**Question:**

Since I am not only implementing pagination but also real time updates (with collection insertions), the `.limit()` operator seems to be not working in my case.

How does one implement a pagination with real time updates (without double reads)?

**Side Notes:**

I watched how [Todd Kerpelman devoures a massive gummy bear while explaining pagination](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU), but in the video it seems to be not so trivial (and a point was made that a tradeoff might be necessary).

If further code from my side is required please say so in the comments.

For the scenario of comments it does not really makes sense that an item is inserted into the middle of the (sorted) collection. However I would like to understand how it should be implemented if the scenario requires such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

this may come as a very late answer. The OP probably won't need help anymore, however for anyone who should stumble on this I wrote a tutorial with a solution that partly solve this:

- the Bloc keep a list of stream subscription to keep trace of realtime updates to the list.
- however concerning the insertion problem, since when you will have paginated streams based on a document cursor, upon insertion or deletion you necessarily need to reset your pagination stream subscriptions unless it is the last page.
  Hence my solution around it was to update the list when modifications occur but reset it when insertions or deletions occur.

Here is the link to the tutorial :
https://link.medium.com/2SPf2Qsbsgb